# Javascript fetch value from network response

Tags: javascript, jquery

I had this this function and what it does to fetch value from network response and I manage to display the output `0: {recipeName: value_1}` and `1: {recipeName: value_2}`. But now the problem I want to display the result together with an alert message. Any idea how to make alert message display only once but the result display in loop?

```js
function (e) {
  var returnedData = JSON.parse(e.responseText);
  console.log(returnedData);

  if(returnedData.length != 0){
    for (var x=0; x < returnedData.length; x++ ){
      var listOfRecipe = '('+[x]+') ' + returnedData[x]['recipeName'];
    }
    alert("Recipe cannot be deactivated, it is used in the following sub recipes: " + listOfRecipe);
  }
}
```

Current output

> Recipe cannot be deactivated, it is used in the following sub recipes:
>   (1) value_2

What I want

> Recipe cannot be deactivated, it is used in the following sub recipes:
>   (0) value_1 (1) value_2

Comment: what is the current content of your alert now ?

Comment: Recipe cannot be deactivated, it is used in the following sub recipes: (1) value_2

Comment: i mean in your current work, what is the result on that ? seems it's already working in our code

Comment: Did you mean keep this alert active while updating its content constantly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Decalare your listofRecipe outside of your loop. Then change your code into this

```
function (e) {
  var returnedData = JSON.parse(e.responseText);
  var listOfRecipe  = ''
  console.log(returnedData);

  if(returnedData.length != 0){
    for (var x=0; x < returnedData.length; x++ ){
       listOfRecipe += '('+[x]+') ' + returnedData[x].recipeName;
    }
    alert("Recipe cannot be deactivated, it is used in the following sub recipes: " + listOfRecipe);
  }
}
```

Comment: I dont think the outcome will change. Still getting the same result. I still getting the last result which is `value_2`

Comment: I upadted my answer

Comment: forgive me.. I miss the `+=` sign